# Checking and modifying an element in nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara

Let's say if I have multiples of the following code(each with different form name, productForm_1, .._2..._3 etc):

```
<form id="productForm_7" name="productForm_3" method="post" action="/send/coded.cfm" style="width:110px; display:inline;">    
<div>
    <input type="hidden" value="24775643" name="productID">
    <input class="btn_addToCart" type="submit" value=" " style="cursor:pointer;">
</div>
</form>
```

How would I go around changing the productID in capybara-webkit?
And since the button doesn't have a name/value, how do I specify the button?

I tried

```
page.find_field('productForm_7').find_field("productID").value
```

but that doesn't seem to work at all.

*sorry, I'm new to capybara/nokogiri

Comment: AFAIK you can't do this, and in any case you really should not be doing this. Why do you want to change an ID on the page in an integration test?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions, instead of one. That makes for a confusing and possibly conflicting series of answers and runs a risk of getting no answers and possibly being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- as shioyama pointed out you shouldn't change the value of a hidden field. If it really changes on the page - quite possible if the page has some scripts - you should try to trigger the change in the same way from your test.
- `find_field` finds fields not forms. Your first find is wrong but your second is correct. Try: `page.find('#productForm_7').find_field("productID").value` instead. Capybaras general purpose find method uses CSS selectors by default. In the same way you can find the button `page.find('#productForm_7').find(".btn_addToCart").value` using the CSS class of the button.

However a more capybaraish style is something like this:

```
within '#productForm_7' do
  # fill in values.... for example fill_in '#productID', :with => '123456'
  find('.btn_addToCart').click
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way for you to do what you want:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<form id="productForm_7" name="productForm_3" method="post" action="/send/coded.cfm" style="width:110px; display:inline;">    
<div>
    <input type="hidden" value="24775643" name="productID">
    <input class="btn_addToCart" type="submit" value=" " style="cursor:pointer;">
</div>
</form>
EOT

doc.search('form').select{ |form| form['id'][/productForm_\d+/] }.each do |form|
  hidden_input = form.at('input[name="productID"]')
  hidden_input['value'] = (hidden_input['value'].to_i + 1).to_s
  button = form.at('input.btn_addToCart')
  # do something with button...
end
```